# The difference between TagHelper and TagHelperComponent in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried to find info on this, but everything I found just had one or two unclear sentences.

What is the difference between `TagHelper` and `TagHelperComponent`, and how do I decide whether to use one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

Tag Helper Components allow you to conditionally modify or add HTML elements from server-side code. They work in conjunction with Tag Helpers.

To be precise Tag Helpers will run your Tag Helper Components.

More info you could refer to:

[Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

[Tag Helper Components in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Yes, I've read all of that, but I still don't understand what are they for, and how they differ from each other